# Where can I find environment developments?

Tags: epic-astro-story

I just played through my first 15yr run in this game but I was only able to go from green/marshy areas into the snowy ones which were full of trees. When I would try and get rid of them it would tell me I need the logging ability or the like. After that I became aware of a large boulder to the south of the green lands as well, but again I can not bulldoze the boulder either.

Where do I gain the ability to remove these obstacles so I can expand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to earn the technology: Demolition
It allows you to move environmental obstacles.

- Lvl 1 lets you cut down trees
- Lvl 2 Lets you destroy boulders

Enjoy